# Is there any general tag of [responsive-design] (the description says it is about Responsive Web Design)?

Tags: discussion, tags

I want to ask about responsive design of a android layout, but the [responsive-design] tag description says it is about Responsive Web Design. Should I use [responsive-design] for android questions? if not, what tags can I use for questions about responsive layout in android?

Answer (score 1):

It's just an overly narrow tag description.

Tagging your question with both the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag and the [responsive-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/responsive-design) tag provides sufficient disambiguation. People who don't want to see Android questions can just filter out that tag, and your question along with it.

Although I've never written an Android app, I can't imagine that the fundamental *principles* of responsive design are that much different for Android vs. web apps. You're simply using different widgets. Therefore, the tag is appropriate because you *are* using "Responsive Web Design" principles and practices.

Comment: Even Microsoft uses the term "responsive design" [in their UWP documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/screen-sizes-and-breakpoints-for-responsive-design) (not that they even follow their own design guidelines in their own system apps, which makes you wonder why they even bothered writing the guidelines at all).